# Window Service - waiting for stored procedure to get the results

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0, windows-services

I am running a stored procedure from `C#` Window Service. The stored proc is a quite heavy query and it takes quite a long time.

I want to wait till the stored proc finishes and return the values.

Is there any way to determine that stored proc is finished?

Comment: How are you running the procedure now?  Post your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Threading.Tasks`. following code will put your thread on wait till the task finish.

```
public void CallStoredProcMethod()
{
    var task1 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RunStoredPro());

    // thread will wait there till the operation finish
    task1.Wait();
}

public void RunStoredPro()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnString))
    {
        // your database call
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[System.Data.Common.DbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.aspx) has a [CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) property.

> Gets or sets the wait time before terminating the attempt to execute a
>   command and generating an error. The time in seconds to wait for the command to execute. Note to implementers, it is recommended that 0 means no timeout.

Note that the default for a SqlCommand is 30 seconds. If you set the CommandTimeout property to 0, your call will take as long as the stored procedure takes to execute. The msdn page for the [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) implementation on a SqlCommand has the following example, modified slightly to set the [CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx):

```
static public int AddProductCategory(string newName, string connString)
{
    Int32 newProdID = 0;
    string sql =
        "INSERT INTO Production.ProductCategory (Name) VALUES (@Name); "
        + "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        // this will cause the command to wait until the sproc is finished
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0; 

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = newName;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            newProdID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return (int)newProdID;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> use a return statement in the stored procedure and get the value

for example  as stored procedure

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Validate]
@inputdata varchar(50),
@outputdata varchar(50) output

AS
SET @outputdata = (
SELECT TOP 1 Password FROM dbo.tblUser WHERE Login = @a)

RETURN @outputdata
GO
```

I am here briefly explaining the core code in C#

```
       string returnValue = string.Empty;
         ...............
        SqlConn.Open();
        sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@inputdata", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.Value = Username;
        sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(param);

        SqlParameter retval = sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@outputdata", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        string retunvalue = (string)sqlcomm.Parameters["@outputdata"].Value;
         ......................
         .........
```